# Second return in render not ignored React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: For clarification: the code is working as intended (see image) I am wondering why it is (Why I am rendering both returns. based on @tkausl answer is correct.

Based on this thread: https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/is-it-valid-for-a-render-to-have-more-than-one-return-statement-within-it/395444

and other knowledge I understand it as that I can have more than one return in a render, but only one will run.

However, in the below piece of code both returns are being rendered, and actually the second return uses the ProjectsList variable from the first return. What am I missing here? Why is it rendering both returns?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ProjectCard from "./ProjectCard";
import UndrawADayAtThePark from "react-undraw-illustrations/lib/components/UndrawADayAtThePark";




class Projects extends Component {
  state = {
    projects: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('./src/data/projects.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          projects: response.data,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const projects = this.state.projects;
    let projectsList;

    if (projects.length > 0) {
      projectsList = projects.map((project) => {
        return (
          <div id={"project-" + project.id} key={project.id}>
            <ProjectCard project={project} />
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
      return (
        <div className="ui main container">
          <div className="ui stackable two column grid">
            <div className="column">
              <UndrawADayAtThePark primaryColor='#12283a' height='200px' />
            </div>
            <div className="column">
              <h1 id="projects-header" className="ui header"> My Projects</h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio placeat 
                ex animi reprehenderit officiis reiciendis laboriosam amet tempora illo, 
                molestiae recusandae? Incidunt magnam in natus commodi tempora vel fugit quod.
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="ui stackable four column grid">{projectsList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

The ProjectCard component from the first return AND the lorem ipsum text in the second are both being rendered. Commenting either return out breaks the interface? How can that be?

[image]

Comment: This is not a react or even JS question. This is language-agnostic. If there are projects, there first statement gets executed which includes a return. If there are no projects, that return won't get executed.

Comment: Your first return isn't in render but in the arrow function passed to `map`. This won't return from `render`.

Comment: I am thinking @Adam answer is correct here (Seems that since it is a comment and not and answer I can't select it as the right answer?).  it is not that I want to make it conditional, I am wonder why, given how it is coded, that it isn't already conditional you can say.

(I am wondering why I am rendering both returns. Based on Adams response I am thinking it is because the first return isn't actually rendered it just a piece of logic)

Comment: Sorry meant to say that @tkausl comment is correct here!

Comment: as @tkausl said the reason the map function is not returning from render, is you don't have return in front of it. If you want to render either `this` or `that` you have to make sure it is returning the render function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need you do that if before the last return statement. If you want to make conditional rendering then do it inside the return from the component like this

```js
return (
projectsList.length && projects.map((project) => {
        return (
          <div id={"project-" + project.id} key={project.id}>
            <ProjectCard project={project} />
          </div>
        );
      });
<div className="ui main container">
          <div className="ui stackable two column grid">
            <div className="column">
              <UndrawADayAtThePark primaryColor='#12283a' height='200px' />
            </div>
            <div className="column">
              <h1 id="projects-header" className="ui header"> My Projects</h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio placeat 
                ex animi reprehenderit officiis reiciendis laboriosam amet tempora illo, 
                molestiae recusandae? Incidunt magnam in natus commodi tempora vel fugit quod.
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="ui stackable four column grid">{projectsList}</div>
      </div>
)
```

NOTE: You might add curly braces `{ }`.

In conclusion, if you want to make condition rendering you have to do it inside the return where it goes the HTML. See more in the official React documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Also, the return you are making will only make it break from the if, not from the component. That's why you have to use conditional rendering

Comment: This was also useful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SergioRamirez - this is bad logic. The [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-nullish-coalescing-operator/) only works if projects.length is null or undefined. Did you perhaps mean a single `?`

Comment: @Adam it does not really matter. Suppose it is not null/undefined but it is 0, then it renders nothing. From my perspective, it's a shorthand so that you do not define an else condition using `?` and just define one condition. :) To clarify, I only do this if I'm not going to render something else in case it doesn't fit the first `if` condition.

Comment: @SergioRamirez - completely agree it does not really matter. Code that "does not really matter" shouldn't be present. EDIT: `it's a shorthand so that you do not define an else condition using ? and just define one condition` this is wrong. `??` is a very specific operator with a very specific meaning. You could do `projects.length &&` which is far more semantically correct. Your condition will be executed regardless, so why waste the time evaluating it (or causing a dev to read it while trying to maintain it?)

Comment: OH YES, you are completely right. I forgot about the `&&` operator. It is true, I was referring to that operator. I'll edit this.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer here is tkausls. I think the first render doesn't count as the return of the render because it is inside the map function. So the render only has one return as should be.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).